# How to set Monolog log level per channel in Symfony

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

I'm using Symfony with Monolog to log data to loggly.com. My symfony app uses following configuration:

```
    loggly:
        type: loggly
        token: ...
        level: INFO
        bubble: true
        channels: ["app", "request"]
```

As you can see, I'm logging the channels **app** and **request**. The minimum log level is INFO for both channels.

Now i would like to distinguish the log level per channel like this:

Channel "**app**": INFO (and above)
Channel "**request**": ERROR (and above)

Is there a way to adjust my configuration or do I have to solve this programatically?

Thanks in advance
ninsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loggly_app:
        type: loggly
        token: ...
        level: INFO
        bubble: true
        channels: ["app"]
loggly_request:
        type: loggly
        token: ...
        level: ERROR
        bubble: true
        channels: ["request"]
```

an additional option would be to have [environment specific configs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#different-environments-different-configuration-files) (e.g. when app-info logging wouldn't be required in production).

Comment: Will give this a try! Thanks